# PowerBI - How best to ignore rows where fact doesn't sum to zero?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Given the following table:

| ID | DIM1 | DIM2 | FACT | COMMENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | TEST | -5.00 | SHOULD BE HIDDEN |
| 2 | A | TEST | 5.00 | SHOULD ALSO BE HIDDEN |
| 3 | B | ABC | -1.30 | IGNORED NOTES |
| 4 | B | ABC | 1.30 | MORE IGNORED NOTES |
| 5 | C | TEST | 34.00 | SHOULD BE VISIBLE |
| 6 | A | TEST2 | -2.20 | NOT SHOWN |
| 7 | A | TEST2 | 2.20 | MORE NOT SHOWN |
| 8 | B | ABCD | 7.20 | SHOULD BE SEEN |
| 9 | B | ABC | 1.30 | VISIBLE |

What is the best technique(s) to "ignore rows whose facts cancel out" while keeping all columns (ID and COMMENT in this scenario)?

Preferred result:

| ID | DIM1 | DIM2 | FACT | COMMENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | C | TEST | 34 | SHOULD BE VISIBLE |
| 8 | B | ABCD | 7.20 | SHOULD BE SEEN |
| 9 | B | ABC | 1.30 | VISIBLE |

I had considered doing it in Power Query via a group by DIM1/DIM2/SUM(FACT) WHERE SUM(FACT) is not 0 and then rejoin back to the previous rows to bring the ID and COMMENT back in.

However, I thought there may be a DAX alternative as well.

[Link to example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ESrVIfWQqrGoEJ4zznrQNFa82z6--ILT/view)

Comment: hi, it seems that DIM1/DIM2 cannot be defined as unique, for example ID 3,4,8 hold same [DIM1]&[DIM2]. So i suppose 3 columns of DIM1&DIM2&COMMENT can define unique rows you want. While since [COMMENT] do not show same data for one group for example ID 3&4 are with different comments so we cannot merge them as one group. 
The question is can you add another column of [COMMENT2] to show same comments for same group, or can you distingush some rules so we can make it in PowerQuery, for example remove words of "more" so we can get same comments for ID 3&4. Then i can handle it with DAX.

Comment: Does the row that cancels out always follow the one it is cancelling out?

Comment: @DavidBacci - no, there is no guaranteed sequence

Comment: I have corrected the example.  ID 8 should have NOT matched the same DIM1 and DIM2 values as IDs 3 and 4.

Comment: @Sia - your observations are correct and I have corrected the sample data so that ID8 is not an exact match for 3 and 4.

Comment: sure Shawn, then it can be done. i will give you answer later and please mark it accepted and vote if solve your problem. so i can get points! 

Comment: @Sia - thanks... I will be glad to accept the solution.  To make it more complicated, i realized I needed to add one more scenarios (ID 9).  I have updated the sample table and example file.

Comment: oh i see... just done based on former discussion. now it back to the previous question as currently ID3,4,9 share same DIM1&DIM2. you may need one more column to distingush the groups of ID3,4 and ID9.

Comment: yes, I now think that I have to generate a new surrogate key that includes the value of the fact column (DIM1&DIM2&FACT) so that I am able to uniquely identify the rows and then subtract the positive/negative rows from their DIMs match.